# Find ids in string and replace from array

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string variable which could be something like:

```
var content = "blah blah [media:id=1] blah blah blah [media:id=0] blah blah";
```

And an array of Objects with Image information i.e.

```
var imageArray = [
  {id:0, path:"/images/image.jpg"},
  {id:1, path:"/images/anotherimage.jpg"}
]
```

I need a function to replace the "[media:id=x]" with the corresponding image object path from the imageArray via the id, so that my 'content' variable looks like:

```
"blah blah <img src='/images/anotherimage.jpg' /> blah blah blah <img src='/images/image.jpg' /> blah blah";
```

But I'm not sure where to start with this?

Comment: Use `String#replace` with a replacer function which retrieves the relevant information from `imageArray` based on id. Your regexp will need to "capture" the `x` part so it is passed to the replacer function.

Comment: No regex, but it works: https://jsfiddle.net/jr3L9vb1/ You would need to do a global replace if more than one of the same name exists.

Comment: @HanletEscaño why not adding answer

Comment: @Tushar It was a quick & dirty solution, hoping better ones will show up (like yours) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace the `id`s in the string by it's respective image element.

```
content.replace(/\[media:id=(\d+)\]/g, function(m, id) {
    var path = imageArray.find(o => o.id === Number(id));
    if (path) {
        return `<img src="${path.path}" />`;
    }
    return m;
});
```

The regex `\[media:id=(\d+)\]` will match

1. `\[`: `[` literal
2. `media:id=` literal
3. `(\d+)`: One or more number and put it into captured group
4. `\]`: `]` literal

[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) can be used to find particular element in the array.

```
imageArray.find(o => o.id === Number(id))
```

will get the object whose `id` matches the matched id from the string. If object is found in the array, the `img` tag can be returned to replace it with the element else, complete string can be returned.

```js
var content = "blah blah [media:id=1] blah blah blah [media:id=0] blah blah";
var imageArray = [{
    id: 0,
    path: "/images/image.jpg"
}, {
    id: 1,
    path: "/images/anotherimage.jpg"
}];

var res = content.replace(/\[media:id=(\d+)\]/g, function(m, id) {
    var path = imageArray.find(o => o.id === Number(id));
    if (path) {
        return `<img src="${path.path}" />`;
    }
    return m;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I like this answer but ES6 Arrow functions won't be fully supported

Comment: Bang on! thats it

Comment: `Array.prototype.find` is not supported by `IE`.

Comment: @Hitmands We have [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) for such browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:
I go through the array and check for each id if it exists in the string, if so I replace that part.

```js
var content = "blah blah [media:id=1] blah blah blah [media:id=0] blah blah";

var imageArray = [
  {id:0, path:"/images/image.jpg"},
  {id:1, path:"/images/anotherimage.jpg"}
]

imageArray.forEach(function(element, i){
  var searchedStr= "[media:id="+element.id+"]";

  if(content.indexOf(searchedStr)!==-1)
    {
      var replaceStr = "<img src='"+element.path+"' />";
      content = content.replace(searchedStr,replaceStr);
    }
});
console.log(content);
```

Comment: The 'content' variable would potentially have multiple Media blocks with the same id so in that case this would work so well

Comment: You didn't mention that - but it's fine now since you already got another answer that suits you right! :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple array reduce could help you:

```js
var content = "blah blah [media:id=1] blah blah blah [media:id=0] blah blah";
var imageArray = [
  {id:0, path:"/images/image.jpg"},
  {id:1, path:"/images/anotherimage.jpg"}
]

console.log(
  imageArray.reduce((res, obj) => {
    const 
      {id, path} = obj,
          
      re = new RegExp(`\\[media:id=${id}\\]`)
    ;

    return res.replace(re, `<img src="${path}" />`);
  }, content)
);
```